# Getting NoSuchMethodError net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.HorizontalAlignEnum.getHorizontalTextAlignEnum

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am facing below error when I am trying to generate report with *JasperReports 6.1* in Linux whereas same war file deployed in Windows generated the pdf report but Linux is creating problem.

```
Exception handling request to /BudgetGrantRpt.htm: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.HorizontalAlignEnum.getHorizontalTextAlignEnum(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/HorizontalAlignEnum;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/HorizontalTextAlignEnum;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1303) [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextElement.readObject(JRBaseTextElement.java:839) [jasperreports-javaflow-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What libs are in cp? What version of JasperReports are you using?

Comment: @ Alex Jasper report version-6.1

Comment: What libs are in cp?